# Restoring Deleted Databases on CloudSQL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I know GCP's CloudSQL supports [instance backups](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/restore) of some kind. Also noted that they make it **really easy to create and delete databases** from the CloudSQL instance details -> Databases tab.

I am concerned about how easy it is to delete a database, especially since mistakes happen. Is it possible at all to restore an accidentally-deleted db? I cannot find any docs on how one would go about such a scenario. Or better yet, how to prevent such accidental deletes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for clarification, I'm discussing deleting *databases* on an instance, and not the instances themselves.

Even with a regular SQL instance, [deleting a database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-database.html) is very easy. As long as you have the correct permissions, all it takes is the following:

```
DROP DATABASE db_name
```

So if you want to prevent someone from deleting a database, just don't give them the `DROP` permission on the database.

Cloud SQL follows the same logic. If you check out the docs for [deleting a database](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/databases/delete), you'll see it requires the `sqlservice.admin` scope. Avoid granting users this IAM permission, and they won't be able to delete an instance.

Comment: Is there a way to recover an deleted instance?

Comment: @SeyeongJeong - Cloud SQL has automated backups by default. See here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups